# LINQPAD, user instance and SQL Server 2012

Tags: linqpad

I've never liked the *User instance* when attaching a database in linqpad. It only seemed to work for the SQLExpress edition not the full one. Now it's being depreciated in SQL Server 2012 (which is now released), do you intend to use the new *localdb* feature instead or in addition to the *user instance*?

Answer (score 3):

LINQPad unticks the 'User Instance' checkbox by default if your server name doesn't contain "SQLEXPRESS". However, it does not *disable* the checkbox because it cannot be certain that that instance is not a SQL Express instance simply by the name.

LINQPad will still need to support user instances because it must still support SQL Express 2008 and SQL Express 2005.

Does it let you connect to a SQL 2012 localdb if you enter "(localdb)\v11.0" into the Server box?

Comment: Thanks Joe, 

I installed the new SQL Server Express 2012, but now I can't attach to the databases within username folder (I check the user instance box) so I can't use the normal path for nutshell.mdf in users\username\appdata\roaming\linkpad\

without relocating the nutshell.mdf database to c:\db\ what can I do?

Comment: Putting (localdb)\v11.0 works without the user instance being checked and navigation to the nutshell database. However if I click a different example a new connection is made that looks the same but fails with the message: Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance.

Comment: Instead of creating a new connection, edit the existing connection that LINQPad creates automatically upon opening a sample query. Make sure you click 'Remember this connection' before accepting.

Comment: Having installed Sql Server Express the message similar to: 'Enabling User Instances with sp_configure' appears. 

To solve this execute:

     `exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1` then 
     `reconfigure`